# Rails checkbox custom

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I need to create custom checkbox

now my checkbox is `<%= check_box_tag "user[show_notification]" %>`

i need to add checked/unchecked

```
show_notification its boolean field



<%= check_box_tag "user[show_notification]",checked:User.current.show_notification ? true : false  %>
```

Comment: what do you mean ? can you give us more context ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to check/uncheck the box depending on your boolean value.

According to the API you should be able to do something like this:

```
<%= check_box_tag "user[show_notification]", "1", User.current.show_notification %>
```

*Notice the second parameter "1" which is the value.*

Also for reference see: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-check_box_tag